# Activating virtual environment environment

Tags: python-3.x, flask, virtual-environment

please for a while now i've been trying to activate virtual environment for my windows 7 machine; I've run commands like env\Scripts\activate where env is the installed virtual environment folder in the project, but each time i run the command, it gives me an error like: activate is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Please what could be the problem, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `activate.bat` inside Scripts folder? If yes, run that. If not, delete everything and run `python -m venv env` again and let me know what happens. Please note that you may change `env` to whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Here it is (just google it, there are a lot of post explaining that): 
https://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/Pip-and-virtualenv-on-Windows/